# Display images from Database with IENUMERABLE<> using MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a webapplication using mvc in which i have to display images im using entity framework. here the view contains IEnumerable and i have saved the path in database using nvarcahr(max) datatype . but when i try to run it is displaying an error that encode image in base64... here is my code

## this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<NewSimpleApp.Models.product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


  <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDesc)
        </td>
        <td>        
            <img src="@Url.Content(@Model.Photo)" alt="@Model.ALternateText" />
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ALternateText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductId })
        </td>
    </tr>
```

## this is my Model:

```
namespace NewSimpleApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string ALternateText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## And this is my database:

[image]

Comment: Everything you have looks fine. What is the exact error you're getting? Is there a stacktrace? If so, post it.

Comment: ya it is working good but i want to show the image instead of path .... i am trying to add this code to display a image <img src="@Url.Content(@Model.Photo)" alt="@Model.AlternateText"/> but im getting an error like [ encode image in base64 ] how can i convert string to base64 .... please check my view i have mentioned tr .... thank so  much

Comment: That was what I was asking about. "encode image in base64" is a non-standard error, and you've provided no context for whether it's occurring server-side or client-side. Edit your question to include the *exact* error message in its entirety and the context of where it occurs and how it displays.

Comment: ya ok i will edit it ... and thank you so much